# How to modify Fisheye issue ID scanner

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, jira, atlassian-fisheye

Fisheye is integrated with JIRA and links issues properly if the issue ID is not surrounded by other characters. Example: XY-123 is linked properly. However, we have been using dashes in front of the issues ids (-xy-123) and that isn't picked up. It is a hassle to go back and revise the SVN log and set a new rule going forward. Is there a way to modify the Fisheye scanner to accommodate for this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is concept of **Linkers** that can be configured with different patterns based on what you need:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/linkers-298976904.html

UPDATE: In Fisheye documentation stands that Fisheye doesn't recognise JIRA custom issue key formats (Notes section)

https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/linking-fisheye-to-jira-394464293.html

and you shouldn't use Linkers together with JIRA/Fisheye integration. You can try to use custom Linker and check whether the integration still works.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I am looking for. It is now not detecting anything (I did have to remove the application links that I had with JIRA). I guess I have to get it to rescan all repos?

Comment: Yes, once it has scanned the repo it doesn't go back, you need to do manual rescan (the same is when you change CL description manually)

Comment: Thanks Robert. I have been trying for a while now to get it to use the custom linker but JIRA is not adding anything under the Development tab like it did before. My expression is the one provided in the JIRA issue ID example from the help page you provided. Commit message just contains the issue ID. I did multiple rescans of the repo but to no vail. If you have any other ideas, please do share :)

Comment: Did you check directly in Fisheye whether the commit is there?

Comment: Yes, the commit made it there.. but nothing that matches the modified expression is showing up under the Development tab. Not sure how to debug this any further

Comment: this is the \Regular Expression I am using for the custom Linker: `-([a-zA-Z]{2,10}-[0-9]+)`

Comment: I think the development panel is disabled because you removed app link to Fisheye. You could create your own panel which is not that difficult.